# Bundle FFmpeg with Qt6 application using CMake

Tags: cmake, ffmpeg, c++17

I'm trying to bundle FFmpeg with my Qt6 application that uses CMake as build system on Mac OS system (Apple chip). I tried the following:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    ffmpeg
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git
    GIT_TAG        n5.1.2
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(ffmpeg)

include_directories(
    "/Volumes/ieasybooks/taqtie/build-repo-Qt_6_4_0_for_macOS-Debug/_deps/ffmpeg-src/libavutil"
    "/Volumes/ieasybooks/taqtie/build-repo-Qt_6_4_0_for_macOS-Debug/_deps/ffmpeg-src/libavcodec"
    "/Volumes/ieasybooks/taqtie/build-repo-Qt_6_4_0_for_macOS-Debug/_deps/ffmpeg-src/libavformat"
)

target_link_libraries(
    taqtie
    PRIVATE
    "/Volumes/ieasybooks/taqtie/build-repo-Qt_6_4_0_for_macOS-Debug/_deps/ffmpeg-src/libavutil/libavutil.h"
    "/Volumes/ieasybooks/taqtie/build-repo-Qt_6_4_0_for_macOS-Debug/_deps/ffmpeg-src/libavcodec/libavcodec.h"
    "/Volumes/ieasybooks/taqtie/build-repo-Qt_6_4_0_for_macOS-Debug/_deps/ffmpeg-src/libavformat/libavformat.h"
)
```

But when I include FFmpeg libraries like this:

```cpp
extern "C" {
#ifndef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#endif
#include <avutil.h>
}
```

I got the following error:

```
main.cpp:6:10: In included file: 'libavutil/avconfig.h' file not found
```

I spent like 1 month on this issue and I can't find any solution. I even asked ChatGPT :)

Do you have any idea?

The code of the project could be found here: https://github.com/ieasybooks/taqtie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just to finalize this. Instead of the cmake code I attached above to link FFmpeg libraries, I used the same [FindFFmpeg.cmake](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/blob/188347d69e5902d1644183f82784782d97f4da28/cmake/Modules/FindFFmpeg.cmake) file that used by OBS Studio project on GitHub, and it worked as expected!

I don't know what is the difference yet, I need to read through it carefully and find the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I found this FFmpeg setup: https://github.com/thomas-moulard/visp-deb/blob/master/CMakeModules/FindFFMPEG.cmake, and I used it in my project and it works fine now.

I used it in this way:

```
FIND_PATH(FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_AVUTIL NAMES libavutil/avutil.h)
FIND_PATH(FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_AVCODEC NAMES libavcodec/avcodec.h)
FIND_PATH(FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_AVFORMAT NAMES libavformat/avformat.h)
FIND_PATH(FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_AVDEVICE NAMES libavdevice/avdevice.h)
FIND_PATH(FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_AVFILTER NAMES libavfilter/avfilter.h)
FIND_PATH(FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_SWSCALE NAMES libswscale/swscale.h)
FIND_PATH(FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_SWRESAMPLE NAMES libswresample/swresample.h)
FIND_PATH(FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_POSTPROC NAMES libpostproc/postprocess.h)

target_include_directories(taqtie PRIVATE
    ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_AVUTIL}
    ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_AVCODEC}
    ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_AVFORMAT}
    ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_AVDEVICE}
    ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_AVFILTER}
    ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_SWSCALE}
    ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_SWRESAMPLE}
    ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR_POSTPROC}
)

FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_AVUTIL_LIBRARY NAMES avutil)
FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_AVCODEC_LIBRARY NAMES avcodec)
FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_AVFORMAT_LIBRARY NAMES avformat)
FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_AVDEVICE_LIBRARY NAMES avdevice)
FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_AVFILTER_LIBRARY NAMES avfilter)
FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_SWSCALE_LIBRARY NAMES swscale)
FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARY NAMES swresample)
FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_POSTPROC_LIBRARY NAMES postproc)

target_link_libraries(taqtie PRIVATE
    ${FFMPEG_AVUTIL_LIBRARY}
    ${FFMPEG_AVCODEC_LIBRARY}
    ${FFMPEG_AVFORMAT_LIBRARY}
    ${FFMPEG_AVDEVICE_LIBRARY}
    ${FFMPEG_AVFILTER_LIBRARY}
    ${FFMPEG_SWSCALE_LIBRARY}
    ${FFMPEG_SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARY}
    ${FFMPEG_POSTPROC_LIBRARY}
)
```

And finally I can import the libraries like this:

```
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#include <libpostproc/postprocess.h>
```

Thanks for your help! Very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For more information, check the discussion here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/141950/bundle-ffmpeg-with-qt6-application-using-cmake